# How to use variable including special symbol in awk?

Tags: variables, awk, symbols, backslash

For my case, if a certain pattern is found as the second field of one line in a file, then I need print the first two fields. And it should be able to handle case with special symbol like backslash.

My solution is first using sed to replace \ with \\, then pass the new variable to awk, then awk will parse \\ as \ then match the field 2.

```
escaped_str=$( echo "$pattern" | sed 's/\\/\\\\/g')    
input | awk -v awk_escaped_str="$escaped_str"  '$2==awk_escaped_str { $0=$1 " "     $2 " "}; { print } '
```

While this seems too complicated, and cannot handle various case.

Is there a better way which is more simpler and could cover all other special symbol?

Comment: What does your pattern look like? `$awk_escaped_str` should not have the `$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to pass a shell variable to awk without backslashes being interpreted is to pass it in the arg list instead of populating an awk variable outside of the script:

```
$ shellvar='a\tb'

$ awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" 'BEGIN{ printf "<%s>\n",awkvar }'
<a      b>

$ awk 'BEGIN{ awkvar=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; printf "<%s>\n",awkvar }' "$shellvar"
<a\tb>
```

and then you can search a file for it as a string using `index()` or `==`:

```
$ cat file
a       b
a\tb

$ awk 'BEGIN{ awkvar=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]="" } index($0,awkvar)' "$shellvar" file
a\tb

$ awk 'BEGIN{ awkvar=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]="" } $0 == awkvar' "$shellvar" file
a\tb
```

You need to set `ARGV[1]=""` after populating the awk variable to avoid the shell variable value also being treated as a file name. Unlike any other way of passing in a variable, ALL characters used in a variable this way are treated literally with no "special" meaning.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Well as I tried, this also works:
awk 'BEGIN{  printf "<%s>\n",ARGV[1] }' "$shellvar"
So, is there any advantage that passing the ARGV[1] to awkvar, then using awkvar in awk script? Or both are OK.

Comment: Note what I said towards the bottom of my answer - you MUST set `ARGV[1]=""` before the end of the BEGIN section or awk will try to open whatever value it contains as a file, so unless you plan to do all of your processing in the BEGIN section you have no choice but to populate an awk variable from ARGV[1] before clearing it.

Comment: Beautiful!! I just used this clever approach in [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34639482/1983854).

Answer (score 2):

There are three variations you can try without needing to escape your pattern:

This one tests literal strings. No regex instance is interpreted:

```
 $2 == expr
```

This one tests if a literal string is a subset:

```
 index($2, expr)
```

This one tests regex pattern:

```
 $2 ~ pattern
```