# sed escape user input string

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I am using sed for string replacement in a config file.

User has to input the string `salt` and then I replace this `salt` string in the config file:

```
Sample config file myconfig.conf

CONFIG_SALT_VALUE=SOME_DUMMY_VALUE
```

I use the command to replace dummy value with value of `salt` entered by the user.

```
sed -i s/^CONFIG_SALT_VALUE.*/CONFIG_SALT_VALUE=$salt/g" ./myconfig.conf
```

*Issue* : value of `$salt` can contain any character, so if `$salt` contains `/` (like `12d/dfs`) then my above sed command breaks.

I can change delimiter to `!`, but now again if `$salt` contains `amgh!fhf` then my sed command will break.

How should I proceed to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

[You can use almost any character as `sed` delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33914360/1983854). However, as you mention in your question, to keep changing it is fragile.

Maybe it is useful to use `awk` instead, doing a little bit of parsing of the line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{repl=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; FS=OFS="="}
     $1 == "CONFIG_SALT_VALUE" {$2=repl}
     1' "$salt" file
```

As one liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN{repl=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; FS=OFS="="} $1 == "CONFIG_SALT_VALUE" {$2=repl}1' "$salt" file
```

This sets `=` as field separator. Then, it checks when a line contains `CONFIG_SALT_VALUE` as parameter name. When this happens, it replaces the value to the one given.

To prevent values in `$salt` like `foo\\bar` from being interpreted, as that other guy commented in my original answer, we have the trick:

```
awk 'BEGIN{repl=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""} ...' "$var" file
```

This uses the answer in [How to use variable including special symbol in awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25186581/1983854) where Ed Morton says that

> The way to pass a shell variable to awk without backslashes being
>   interpreted is to pass it in the arg list instead of populating an awk
>   variable outside of the script.

and then

> You need to set `ARGV[1]=""` after populating the awk variable to
>   avoid the shell variable value also being treated as a file name.
>   Unlike any other way of passing in a variable, ALL characters used in
>   a variable this way are treated literally with no "special" meaning.

This does not do in-place editing, but you can redirect to another file and then replace the original:

```
awk '...' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

Comment: awk is indeed the better tool for this +1

Comment: On GNU awk, this fails if `salt='foo\\bar'`

Comment: @thatotherguy after some research I found a solution for this! Ed Morton put some light as usual : )